# python subprocess.call() can not run on multiple nodes in pbs system?

Tags: python, subprocess, mpi

My aim was to use the pbs qsub command to run a python script. I allocated 2 nodes in the pbs script "#PBS -l nodes=cu25:ppn=32+cu26:ppn=32", and hopes the "subprocess.call(command)" in the python script can run on these two nodes. However, I got an error "cu25.114979hfi_userinit: assign_context command failed: Device or resource busy cu25.114979hfp_gen1_context_open: hfi_userinit: failed, trying again (1/3)".

The following are deatils of the pbs script run.pbs:

```py
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N test-cpu
#PBS -l nodes=cu25:ppn=32+cu26:ppn=32
#PBS -l walltime=720:00:00
#PBS -q batch
#PBS -j oe

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
NPROCS=`wc -l < $PBS_NODEFILE`

python3 run.py
```

My python file run.py:

```py
import subprocess

command = "mpirun vasp_std"
with open('vasp.out', 'w') as f:
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True, stdout=f, cwd=None)
```

I use the qsub run.pbs to submit my work, and hope the command "mpirun vasp_std" can run on the allocated two nodes. However, the following error happened:

```py
cu25.115070PSM2 can't open hfi unit: -1 (err=23)
cu26.99380PSM2 can't open hfi unit: -1 (err=23)
cu26.100027PSM2 can't open hfi unit: -1 (err=23)
cu25.114979PSM2 can't open hfi unit: -1 (err=23)
cu25.114926PSM2 can't open hfi unit: -1 (err=23)
cu25.115487PSM2 can't open hfi unit: -1 (err=23)
cu25.114932PSM2 can't open hfi unit: -1 (err=23)
[mpiexec@cu25] HYDU_sock_write (../../utils/sock/sock.c:418): write error (Bad file descriptor)
[mpiexec@cu25] HYD_pmcd_pmiserv_send_signal (../../pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_cb.c:253): unable to write data to proxy
[mpiexec@cu25] ui_cmd_cb (../../pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:175): unable to send signal downstream
[mpiexec@cu25] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (../../tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status
[mpiexec@cu25] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (../../pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:507): error waiting for event
[mpiexec@cu25] main (../../ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:1148): process manager error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@cu25] HYDU_sock_write (../../utils/sock/sock.c:418): write error (Bad file descriptor)
```

If I just use one node, it works well. How can I run the script on multiple nodes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if you simply `mpirun vasp_std` from your PBS script?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, it works well if I simply use `mpirun vasp_std` in pbs script. However, the python file above is just a simplified version for testing. I need to use python to process the data first, and then use the for loop to perform batch calculations, so it is necessary to use the python scripts.

Comment: did you produce the error with the full blown python script or just the one you posted?

Comment: The problems encountered with the full or simplified version of the python script are the same. They both have the same error message.

Comment: You should almost never use `shell=True`. It is both inefficient and can cause surprising problems. In your code it is not necessary. Simply do `subprocess.call(["mpirun", "vasp_std"], shell=False, ...)`. More important is that your example code is obviously (I hope) not what you are really executing because your `python run.py` can be replaced by `mpirun vasp_std >vasp.out`. I am downvoting your question because it is obvious you are not accurately conveying your actual code or you have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: @KurtisRader since the error can be reproduced with the trivial python script, I do not understand why you are downvoting this question.

Comment: @KurtisRade Sorry for not being clear in my question. Because the complete python code involves many processes of processing structures with ase, these processes have no effect on the generation of errors. What I want to do is to execute the vasp_std program on multiple nodes in parallel through python code. In order to make it easier to read, so I only show a simplified version of the python code.

Comment: I think I have found the reason. It may be a bit funny. When I change the nodes from 25, 26 (`#PBS -l nodes=cu25:ppn=32+cu26:ppn=32`) to 18, 19 (`#PBS -l nodes=cu18:ppn=32+cu19:ppn=32`), the program can run normally. So the error should be due to the fact that the two nodes I initially chosed cannot be parallelized.

Comment: @zihaojiao that does not explain why it worked when you used `mpirun` directly.